# Exporting C++ types from database to another

Tags: ida

I have a pe dll binary with it's pdb file. I'd want to use this file's types in another database.

I tried to export the types using "Create C header file" and "Dump typeinfo to IDC file", but neither worked properly. Trying to import the generated C header file to the second database fails due to templates. The exported IDC file doesn't include all of the types present in the first database.

Seems like IDA doesn't support importing types that use C++ features, like templates. I was wondering if there's any way to work around this. I wouldn't want to start manually renaming and importing the types since there's thousands of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Warning: hack!

1. with the first IDB open, copy the `idbname.til` to another place
2. run `tilib -#- idbname.til`
3. copy it to IDA's `til/pc` (or matching processor) directory.
4. in the second IDB, add the type library from the Type Libraries list.
5. types are now available even though they're not shown in Local Types. You can, for example, "Add standard structure", or use them in the decompiler.

This is not officially supported so you may run into all kinds of issues (e.g conflicts between type libraries).